# Converting mouse position way off

Tags: c++, winapi

I've got a remote screen that takes mouse position then converts the position into the captured screens position but the position is always off. I'm not the greatest at math but I'm sure my conversion is correct. The image size I get in correlation with the screen along with the window size is correct. The only thing that ends up being off is my click point after conversion.

** Also I know I have no error checking. This is to help with readability.

EXAMPLE: I want to click on `Screen` point `1102x` `999y`. The `Remote Window` point is approx `676` `584`. After conversion the point gets translated to `1081.5` `935.3`. I would understand maybe a few pixels off because its hard to click on that exact spot through the RW but its getting translated 60 pixels up and 20 pixels left.

Lets say that my remote screen is 800 x 600 and the captured is 1280 by 1024.
to get the difference I use (1280 / 800)*Clickpointx and  (1024 / 600)*Clickpointy.

My problem is sWidth and sHeight are always off by at least 20 and sometimes are off by upwards of 80 depending on where the click is inside the window.

```
        POINT p;
        float sWidth;
        float sHeight;
        GetCursorPos(&p);
        RECT rect;
        GetWindowRect(hWnd, &rect); // Get Window Size
        ScreenToClient(hWnd, &p); // convert points relative to screen to points relative to window 
        float wWidth = rect.right - rect.left;
        float wHeight = rect.bottom - rect.top;
        Gdiplus::Image* image = Gdiplus::Image::FromStream(sRemote_Handler.istream); //Get Captured image Size;
        float iWidth = image->GetWidth();
        float iHeight = image->GetHeight();
        INPUT input;
        input.type = INPUT_MOUSE;
        input.mi.time = 0;
        float pointx = p.x; 
        float pointy = p.y;
        sWidth = (iWidth / wWidth)*pointx; // divide image width by screen width
        sHeight = (iHeight / wHeight)*pointy; // divide image height by screen height
        input.mi.dx = sWidth*(65536.0f / iWidth); //convert to pixels
        input.mi.dy = sHeight*(65536.0f / iHeight); // ^
        input.mi.dwFlags = MOUSEEVENTF_ABSOLUTE | MOUSEEVENTF_MOVE;
        SendInput(1, &input, sizeof(input)); // move mouse
```

I've tried changing the conversion method to (Clickpointx*1280)/800 and  (Clickpointy*1240)/600.  Still the same results.

```
        sWidth = (pointx * iWidth) / wWidth;
        sHeight = (pointy * iHeight) / wHeight;
```

Changed the conversion method once more.  Same Results

```
        sWidth = (pointx / iWidth)*wWidth;
        sHeight = (pointy / iHeight)*wHeight;
```

**EDIT**

I've came to the conclusion that its the `ScreenToClient` windows function. 
When clicking in the bottom right corner which should be damn near `800,600` both values are around 50 less then what they should be. When I click in the top left both values are where they should be. The numbers are reporting as `0,1`. It seems as though the further I get from the initial `0,0` point the less accurate `ScreenToClient` gets.

Comment: `65536.0f` is pixel density ?

Comment: From what I've read its the coordinate system Microsoft uses. '0,0' top left to '65536,65536' bottom right.

Comment: that one is for high resolution point you have to check for remote dispay resolution point to calculate ..

Comment: The problem I'm having is prior to the conversion with Microsoft's coordinate system.

Comment: If I correctly remember, this could be related to different origins: one value pair having an absolute origin (relative to screen), the other having a relative origine (relative to a window). Or one pair relative to the application window (including frame) and the other relative to the client window (only inside).

Comment: "The ScreenToClient function converts the screen coordinates of a specified point on the screen to client-area coordinates." Which I assume is inside the window due to the fact that I've tested the click inside the client window(not including frame) on the top left and it was as close to `(0,0)` as humanly possible to click.

Comment: You should pair `ScreenToClient` with `GetClientRect` not `GetWindowRect`.

Comment: Please verify that your application is per-monitor DPI aware. (I don't know why it says that GDI+ applications are automatically dpi-aware. GDI+ cannot make your application do math differently.) Call `GetProcessDpiAwareness` and verify that it reports your process as `  PROCESS_PER_MONITOR_DPI_AWARE`.

Comment: @BenVoigt This Worked! I never realized there was this other function specifically for the client rather than the window. Raymond the dpi aware did not make any difference. If you Want BenVoigt Post your answer and Ill mark it correct for you.